# Macro to give all Possible outcomes

Tags: vba, excel, math, excel-2013

I have a question regarding possible outcomes.

There are 9 games per week, in every game there are 3 possible results:

- Home (H) win
- Away (A) win
- Draw (D)

Is there a macro that can give me all possible combination of results for all the games.

[image]

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561935/excel-vba-all-possible-combination)

Comment: @ARich I looked for a question but didn't find. Can you please send me a link to the duplicate?

Comment: "Possible duplicate" from my comment is a link.

Comment: You just need 9 nested For loops iterating over a 3-member array of ("H","A","D")

Comment: @ARich sorry i dint catch that but looking over the other question I do believe its the same name but the manner in solving will be different...

Comment: @TimWilliams please let me know if this is a good start...

Comment: Your question is about permutations - it's not a "knapsack" problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Dim i, j, rowloc, teams As Integer
Dim result(2) As String

result(0) = "H"
result(1) = "A"
result(2) = "D"
teams = 9

For i = 0 To 2
    For j = 1 To teams
        rowloc = i * teams + j
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowloc, 1).Value = "Team " & j
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowloc, 2).Value = result(i)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowloc, 3).Value = "Team " & j + teams
    Next
Next
```